# Long time until answer accepted?

Tags: support

I answered [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410773/getting-0-values-in-return-from-a-sub-procedure-vb-net/12412178#12412178) back on September 13, 2012, and on September 12, **2014** I was notified it had been accepted as the answer.

Does this mean that that really was the date it was accepted, or was something in the SO database catching up?

I had another one recently, before that, where about a year had passed between my answer and the acceptance; I took that as genuine, but two of them with such long acceptance times starts to look like something might be awry.

**Addendum:** I will post an answer saying "Yeah, that happens" after a respectable time for comments. I may wait some time (current target: four-*and-a-bit* years. :) ) before accepting it.

Comment: I'd say the linked question has nothing odd to it. The user has only asked one question, so clearly isn't that active.

Comment: It's pretty normal; I've done it as well after checking to see if I've accepted everything I should have.

Comment: Me too, I have been guilty of going back and trawling for "easy-cheese" yaknow ? Especially on sluggish Saturdays.. lemme go scavenge for some spare coins now, ah but first I reheat 2-day McDonalds java :p

Comment: I've gotten answers accepted as much as four years after I posted them. This is not unusual - a lot of new users aren't aware of how to accept answers (or why they should), and don't learn about it for some time, and then go back to take care of their earlier questions. (There is also no requirement that any answer be accepted, so there are lots of questions that have *no* accepted answer that have been out there for several years.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Judging by the comments, that is just the way it is: some users go back over their questions a long time after asking and tidy up.