# What to do with your answer when no one, including OP, is interested in the post

Tags: discussion, answers

Example: Link Removed, sorry

Sometimes I go ahead post an answer to a question and then wait endlessly for OP to show any interest in the post itself, let alone my answer.

If there are other answers one can say that OP might be looking at those answers and that is absolutely fine but i am talking about situations where that answer is the only answer. No comments/votes whatsoever by the OP or anyone for that matter.

I feel like I  wasted time on such answers and sometimes I feel like deleting those answers because no one is interested in that question/answer post.

But i don't want to just go ahead delete stuff after a couple of days with no reactions because this site does not focus on short term problem solving for the OP and someone can come in future and learn something from that post.

So is it fine if i go ahead delete such answers (mine)? Shouldn't the OP usually be willing to waste a few seconds of their time to take part in activity related to their question when others have wasted some of their time to answer what they asked?

**Please** don't go ahead start voting on the answer thinking i brought it up because I want some votes, that's not what i mean.

**Edit**
I just removed the link because I don't feel all those up-votes that the answer is getting are well deserved. That post is getting all the attention just because of this question and I sort of feel bad about getting up-votes this way.

Comment: I upvoted the answer as it actually answered a question I had - it is a great answer - please don't delete it.

Comment: Friend, methinks after 3+ years of hard work on this site you're in dire need of a morale boost, and not a true answer to this question. Because otherwise you'd be seriously suggesting committing borderline vandalism because someone isn't courteous.

Comment: "Please don't go ahead start voting on the answer thinking i brought it up because I want some votes, that's not what i mean." My young Padawan, there is no such thing as rejecting the Meta effect. Posting about an answer on meta, by definition, irrevocably invokes the Meta effect. Instead, you must learn to ***~~~EMBRACE IT~~~***.

Comment: You worry after a couple of *days*? Try *years*,,, [Long time until answer accepted?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272318/1115360)

Comment: Not so much on my own answers, but if I see that someone has has plenty of opportunity to respond to a helpful answer and has not responded or voted, I will downvote them.

Comment: @halfer Are you saying you would downvote a perfectly good question just because the OP didn't comment/vote/accept?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: absolutely, yes, if (a) answers have come in that evidently took a great deal of time to compose, (b) no-one has voted on those answers and thus it is clear the OP has not either, and (c) a good deal of time has elapsed between an answer coming in and the OP's last log in time. My purpose here is in supporting the community by encouraging lazy OPs to use the voting/feedback tools at their disposal.

Comment: (I am more than happy to hear views on that, though I think it is pretty settled on _Meta_ that people may vote for any reason they wish, as long as it is not serially by user).

Comment: @halfer Way to screw with SO's primary indicator of post quality. The consensus on Meta is that although you *can* vote however you want, you *should* vote on the content, not the user.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: thanks for your feedback. My view is that the OP has earned the downvote, and if they do not want their post quality indicator to be (ahem) "screwed with", then they can start interacting with the community. I will often comment in relation to this, so it is not as if they would be left guessing why they have received a downvote.

Comment: Your question just backfired, we did upvote your answer; sincerely, sorry.

Comment: Just for fun I put together [a query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/388456/498812/tumbleweed-answers) that lists non-upvoted answers posted by a user on questions with low view counts (I apologize for what I'm sure is an atrocious query). You've got 19 such answers. Jon Skeet has 4.

Comment: If "downvoting to hell" is a thing, is "upvoting to heaven" also a thing?

Comment: If I remember right, SO used to have a rating on a user's profile as to the percentage of questions for which they had selected an answer. It doesn't seem to be there, now, though. Perhaps SO removed that because of all the reasons mentioned here - basically that regardless of whether it was marked as answered, the answers given may be helping a bunch of people!

Comment: @leanne: Spot on.

Comment: Haha lol, "Please don't go ahead start voting on the answer thinking i brought it up because I want some votes, that's not what i mean" - no escape. The only way is to remove the link :D But wait, you don't love repz? don't pretend :P

Comment: @nicael: once I got to 10K, I didn't care about it so much, though it may vary from one person to another. Now I'll add rep to other people's questions, and accept downvotes without being too bothered about it.

Comment: @leanne: yes, I rather miss that widget `:-)`

Comment: `What to do with your answer when no one, including OP, is interested in the post?` Post the link on Meta, apparently.

Comment: I tend to answer questions in the .htaccess/apache tags. They don't attract much attention, and a lot of them never get accepted or voted upon. I do however, sometimes get votes or even accepts on them after months or years. I am not sure why. Maybe they got reminded by a popup when browsing stackoverflow again, maybe someone else found it, maybe stackoverflow send them a mail that they still had a question up. In any case. Even if you don't get an immediate upvote/accept, it doesn't mean it didn't help someone, or won't get accepted/voted upon at some point.

Comment: There is a very real thing within SO, whereby a 'niche' subject area is less rewarding - no matter how amazing your answer, you don't get the views, so you don't get the rep. I do wonder sometimes if a rep-bonus scaling by 'tag busy-ness' might be a good thing.

Comment: @Michael wow, I have 46. I'm not sure what that says about me...

Comment: @BoltClock wow that's a big meta effect at that! Usually the only meta effect I manage to create is the down-votes :)

Comment: @Sobrique: I've realized that I'm not going to get the big rep easily, or get many badges quickly, over in the x86 asm / performance optimization corner of SO where I like to answer questions.  That's just the way it is.  I'm not going to try to compete to answer the questions that more people will see just for the rep, because I'm pretty sure my time is most valuable when spent on the area where I have what seems to be quite rare knowledge / interest.  Very few other people ever answer questions with detailed performance analysis of asm code, even though Agner Fog's guides are easy to read...

Comment: @Sobrique:  As long as I'm seeing interesting questions to answer, and helping people out, and leaving useful answers for people who stumble on them later, I'm happy.  It'd be nice to get bigger rep rewards, but I don't think it would make much difference in how I use the site.

Comment: careful @Hanky웃Panky, now people will look your profile and randomly upvote an other of your answers :p

Comment: @halfer: I have to say that I don't think downvoting people's questions for not being polite enough to upvote / accept answer is very productive either. Either the question is good, or it isn't. It doesn't matter if the OP is a jerk or not.

Comment: So your answer has obviously been meta effected, but what was the question score before this post? What was it when you posted your answer? It's sitting at -5 now and that may be a big part of why nobody (including the OP) is interested. A lot of people won't bother looking at a -5 question. The OP may have been sufficiently discouraged by that -5 to not bother coming back. Personally, I wouldn't worry about it. It is annoying, but they are just imaginary internet points.

Comment: @MattBurland: thanks for your thoughts. I'm generally minded to disagree, since without community (spirit) the site is nothing, and would not be useful. I do admit there are some interesting philosophical problems with "enforcing" politeness, though in downvoting and chasing away help vampires, are we not doing exactly that?

Comment: Out of interest, there are some situations where I will comment instead of downvoting e.g. I often comment if provided solutions were helpful. If I then find I am ignored, downvoting is pretty much the last sanction left.

Comment: @halfer: Without good questions (and answers) the site would not be useful. Community or spirit is pretty secondary to that. Not that the question here was a particularly good question (I don't think it was, it showed no effort on the part of the OP).

Comment: @Matt both scores were 0 at that time. And frankly those votes only look good in that green notification bar that pops up every now and then, my only frustration was that OP doesn't participate in the discussion on their own post sometimes, like absolutely no feedback to anyone, no reply to even comments

Comment: @MattBurland: without community, there would be no-one to answer questions (sorry, I intended to infer that in my first reply - I should have made it clearer!). I think community cohesion is necessary to encourage this (though this is more of a feeling that scientifically proven `:-)`).

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky: To be fair, looking at the question it looks like the OP put very little, if any effort in to it from their side. There is no code, just a request for *how to do x* (and not as clearly stated as it might be). If you answer low effort questions, then I wouldn't be too surprised if the OP puts very little effort into looking at or acknowledging the answers. That's not to say I "blame the victim".

Comment: Yes that surely makes sense

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky if you want to get rid of the meta effect, better remove any hint that there was a link from the text. Its still only a single click away to be found and referring to things that "once were here" only invites curiosity again.

Comment: FYI, your answer was condescending (first you must understand...) and also wrong (didn't consider daylight savings, the crux of my question). I don't understand why you'd get so cut about it.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Don't delete it - it could (and probably will) be useful to someone else. Many new users don't have the culture and habit to up-vote or accept answers once their problem is solved. It might take more time before someone else googles that and your answers starts showing up in results. I also have such answers but after some time it seems they've been helpful to someone else as they start gaining up-votes.

PS: Great answer to the timezone question BTW :)

Comment: Thanks! that sure makes sense.

Comment: I agree. I'm still in the early stages of my software career and I'm still learning. If I find a question/answer that helped me learn and guided me to a solution for a problem I'm having, that post will get an upvote from me. I've upvoted posts back from 2008 already - trust me, as long as the technology stays relevant, the info in a post will remain useful for a long time.

Answer (score 24):

No, you should never delete an answer solely for the reason of it not getting accepted or up-voted. The fact that nobody has taken the time to give feedback on your answer does not mean it's not (been) useful to anyone.

Your answer might help future readers with the same problem. If you would have deleted your answer, they would have to ask the same question again. So, by deleting your answer you're basically slamming the door in the face of people having the same issue. Just leave it there.

The only legitimate reason (IMHO) to delete an answer if is you made a mistake in it (like you misinterpreted the question the first time your read it and are giving the wrong solution) or by overlooking certain things that might be potentially harmful or have no added value to the question asked. For example, if your answer uses a deprecated function that is strongly discouraged from using anymore, you could delete that answer (although it would be better yet to improve it to use the proper code).

SO is a Q&A community whose archive is more valuable then any separate question/answer. By keeping answers out there, you contribute to the quality of that archive.

Comment: Sure does make sense! actually the sole reason is not lack an up-vote. It is lack of OP's interest in anything on that post. No comments, no further clarification requests, no responses to questions people ask in comments. Like a one of question submission with no further interest, but yes you are right, should just leave the answer there.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Also keep in mind that sometimes the OP might have already solved the problem on their own and just doesn't come back to the question anymore. But in that case it's also still a good idea to leave the answer untouched.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think you should delete it - we've all been there, and it's all too easy to have that initial reaction but the point to remember is that this is a *community* and that answer could be silently helping others in a big way.

If the OP has a low rep, or is a new member - it might be worth putting a comment with a reminder "Don't forget to accept the answer that helped you" etc...

This type of comment isn't a plea for votes or rep, this is simply a gentle nudge to encourage that person to become an active part of the community.

Comment: Thanks Macro Man, I would be more interested in adding a comment asking them to just take part in the discussion itself related to the problem but then they aren't responsive at all so i guess just leave it be.

Comment: This is what I've done with a couple of my answers that have similarly been ignored.   So far the comment has also been ignored, leaving me to think the user was a fly-by-night.

Comment: I wouldn't bother nudging the OP. Just leave it and move on. A post that isn't bad, is worth leaving. It does no harm, for all it would be nice to get a response/reward.

Answer (score 6):

The purpose of posting an answer isn't (or shouldn't be) to seek reputation or praise. It's just to share knowledge and be helpful *because you can*.

Acting petulant "well if you don't like it I'll take it back" is totally at odds with the ethos of SE, though I'm sure we all feel that way sometimes!

Comment: Except that no up- or downvote, nor acceptance of answer or even a comment on it can mean that no-one has even read your answer. I also post answers a lot, and sometimes they go completely ignored. Even a small comment on it would cheer me up.

Answer (score 5):

I am guilty of this usually when Im trying many different ways in which to solve my problem and then when it works get too excited and lose focus on the post that solved it for me.

All the questions and answers on here or any other site help people an part or in full, sometimes the answer slaps you in the face from the search results, because you can see that you over looked a simple . in your code "we've all been there".

please dont delete or stop answering, people like you keep tech stuff running and relieve headaches.

Answer (score 5):

Leave it up!

Think of it as creating a record for the entire future of humanity. Someone, someday, may find it and appreciate it. I get upvotes and comments on questions or answers I posted years ago.

I'll even ask a question, it gets zero attention, I find the answer myself and post an answer myself later, still zero attention, yet I know now that that is addressed, this technical problem is solved forevermore. Such is the wonder of the internet.

All this doesn't necessarily translate into upvotes, but that's more a mechanism to get people to do it, vs. the site's raison d'être.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, sometimes, I do not have the time to react appropriately to an answer. For example, my team may have already found a different solution or has decided to use a completely alternative approach. If the answer is not short enough, I do not have the time to actually check if it would solve my original problem and therefore I cannot accept it as a "working solution". So it looks like I would not react to it at all, however, that's not true: often I come back to it later on when I have some private time to politely mark them as answered or at least upvote them.

TL;DR: Please don't delete your answers :-)

Comment: I think it's quite understandable that your need for a solution may have moved on before an answer comes in. However, if (a) an answer is non-trivial and has obviously taken a lot of time to write, and (b) if an asker does not respond in any fashion for a long duration, I think it is fair if the answerer and/or the community regards this as discourteous. Not saying you do that, but I think it is worth stating explicitly.

Comment: Pro tip: leave a comment to state that you are thankful and will follow-up on the answer at a later point.

Comment: @halfer - There's absolutely nothing in SO rules that warrants any down-voting based on OP's level of participation.

Comment: @PM77-1: and there is nothing explicitly to forbid it, either.

Comment: @halfer - I do not believe it to be true.  SO lists the specific reasons for down-voting. OP participation is not one of them.

Comment: @PM77-1: if you can point me to the directive(s) you have in mind, I'll certainly consider it. Thanks.

Comment: what does TL;DR mean in this context?

Answer (score 2):

I have about 2/3 the number of answers you have (with less than half the score) and about 1/3 of them are 0 votes. Maybe 1/4 of the 0 votes are accepted. So I understand the frustration with having put an answer in and get no response. But half the success of SO is not in the users but in the people who come behind. The people who Google for an answer and find your question. There are days I hop on SO and I get a random upvote. Those days make me smile and help make it worthwhile.

Hang in there man. You'll probably never know all the people you helped, even if the OP never comes back to appreciate it.

Comment: *"You'll probably never know all the people you helped."*: About [771,000 people](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1570534/hanky-%EC%9B%83-panky) it looks like!

Comment: @Claudiu And growing :)

Answer (score 2):

Leave the answer up, but if you happen to notice the lack of acceptance/interest then is there any harm in a follow up comment to the original question? "Hey Fred, have you had a chance to try the answer?  If you are still struggling, then maybe edit your question with new information so the community can help you further."

Comment: Yes, this is worth thinking about. There are so many lazy gimme-the-codez questions that it is tempting to think all posters are like that; in fact, some people would very much like to reply, normally make a habit of doing so, and will occasionally just forget to respond to a question.