# Dealing with no feedback from low-rep or new users

Tags: discussion, new-users

Sorry if this question is a duplicate, I couldn't find any about this specific nuance or maybe I'm just writing here to vent some frustration.

I have the maybe bad habit to pick up newbie questions on not so popular tags and answer them. Plenty of times neither the question nor the answer get any upvotes and the view count stays pretty low (20-30 at best).

Plenty of times OP just disappears without leaving any kind of feedback, no comment, no upvote, no accept. Sometimes he doesn't even log back to the site anymore.

It's not that I really care about reputation, usually I answer if I find the question a good occasion to review some argument or learn something new while experimenting with a new task.

This lack of feedback can anyway be really frustrating and while until now I ignored the reputation of the asker I'm thinking to proactively avoid non-trivial questions from users below some minimum rep threshold.

I guess this is bad, if everybody did that no newbie would get any answer... so how do you guys cope with this kind of scenario?

Comment: Ping once the user. If unresponsive, move on and find better questions to answer.

Comment: @yivi is that ok? I thought any kind of pinging/ feedback soliciting could pass as rep whoring

Comment: I think that really depends on the comment. There is a huge difference between _"Did my answer help you?"_ and _"If my answer helped you please upvote and accept."_

Comment: Related: [Long time until answer accepted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272318/long-time-until-answer-accepted)

Comment: @AndréKool I honestly can not tell which one is supposed to sound better.

Comment: @Emut Here is my translation: _"Can you give me feedback?"_ and _"Can you give me imaginary internet points?"_ Does that make it clear for you?

Comment: Perhaps note here that historically, Stack Overflow used to display asked/accepted stats in the user badge of everyone who asked a question, but this feature was removed because, well, it tended to polarize responses to new users or something like that.  Here's a 2013 meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate

Comment: @AndrewMorton: good point, also got two 'belated' accepts recently (8 and 11.5 month after my answer). Beside that, there are many answers with a lot of upvotes which have never been accepted by the OP.

Comment: If a question isn't upvoted, if it's truly a "poor" question per the site standards, there's obviously no mandate to answer it, and no one needs to feel bad that the OP didn't get an answer.  If you're more interested in helping people than in building a repository of high-quality questions and answers, you can obviously answer it anyway (I often do), but some might say you're circumventing the intent of the site.

Comment: Also notice that in many tags, the correct response in many cases is to nominate the question as a duplicate of another common, popular question with many answers. You need more reputation to be able to cast close votes, but you can leave a comment of the form `Possible duplicate of <url>`, Duplicates are *good;* they help us collect all the canonical knowledge in one place, and the questions which are closed work as useful signposts for others who are articulating their problem statement similarly.

Comment: It is also funny that on this particular question, you didn't provide any other feedback but voting (maybe?) to the multiple answers you received, and almost no feedback to the multiple comments in your question. Not saying that you should provide feedback, not at all. But that maybe this should help you be more understanding when other users fail to provide feedback to your answers as well.

Comment: @tripleee They can also flag the dupe, which adds the comment automatically and puts the question in the queue. (It also pings me in SOBotics when I'm around if tagged C++. Any Mjolnir can subscribe to this service.)

Comment: @yivi the main point of this question was to see if anyone else shared my frustrations and spawn some discussion about it. And it sure did, lots of helpful and useful insights! Also give a man some time! it's been just a couple of hours since my question.

Comment: I'm ok with you not providing feedback. I was only pointing out the apparent contradiction, hoping to help you "deal" with this frustration from a different point of view. Since you didn't specify what you considered a timely feedback, I had to use my own judgment on that. Peace, and out. :)

Comment: Always make sure that you learn something from answering the question, or have fun answering it. Then, if you get no feedback at all, at least you've learnt something, or had fun. If answering feels like a chore, find a more interesting question. And if a question is not completely clear, ask for clarification, and don't put in too much effort before the asker replies.

Comment: I've had answers accepted 4 years after writing them. So, write your answer if you think it's worthwhile, maybe add a comment, then move on and forget about it!

Comment: Probably came from a drive-by user or a user using a sock puppet account to prevent the loss of reputation when asking a question.  In both of those cases, they're not coming back.

Comment: @AndréKool Doesn't accepting answers help other visitors to the question? So could you clarify why is it bad to remind new users to accept _if_ the answer helped?

Comment: @GoodDeeds What I said was in responce to what OP asked about rep whoring. It wasn't my intention to say it is bad but it _can be perceived as_ being bad. My point is to carefully consider how you phrase a comment like that and when/how often you use it.

Comment: @YetAnotherRandomUser _user using a sock puppet account to prevent the loss of reputation when asking a question_ is that a thing?!

Comment: Maybe this will help with a large subset of these questions: Create a homework.stackexchange.com site. Answerers understand that the asker may be pressed for time and can disappear at any moment, presumably moving on to another Q&A site.  Unanswered questions get deleted after 2 weeks of inactivity. Good questions get migrated to stackoverflow.com.

Comment: @filippo yeah.  SO is the only SE site where I have a substantial problem losing rep.  I was even banned for a while.  I think they changed the reinstatement algorithm since then though.  Therefore, if  I can't ask my question on another SE site, I'll make a disposable account just for that one question to see how things shake out on SO.  I learned of the idea while researching how to get my account ban fixed, and that the data shows that most questions come from no-rep or low-rep users.

Comment: I have been wondering whether questioners could be prompted for some sort of 'I ideally need a response by x date' - that would help in prioritising people's input (although obviously a good question is worth answering at some point even if outside the questioner's timescales). Some questioners obviously don't look at SO from Friday to Monday, and why would they, if this is a work related question? - but we have no way of telling what their situation is, at present.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I don't think it's necessary or useful to explicitly go hunting for feedback from OP or on the Q/A itself. You would mostly add noise, with little to no actual gain. After all, you are (or should be) confident your answer is correct and complete *before* posting it, i.e. without specific feedback from OP.

Now regarding your frustration: I suppose this all comes down to your motivation for answering niche "noob" questions.

If you think the question is useful to a broader audience of readers, don't worry about the immediate feedback. If your answer is useful, the votes will come in eventually, as the future readers come by. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31196480/timeline)<sup>†</sup> is an example of exactly that happening to me.

If, on the other hand, the question looks more like the "individual helpdesk" kind, e.g. because the problem is very localized, a lack of feedback and rep-rewards is something you just have to risk if you really want to answer. After all, the goal of this site is to build a Q/A repository, rather than mimicking a tutor, helpdesk, or interactive tutorial. However, as those questions are fundamentally misaligned with the site's main goal, I don't feel like we are losing a lot if people cease to answer them out of "frustration" or for whatever reason.

---

<sup>†</sup>Now of course, [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) is not a niche tag by any means; so your results on smaller tags are likely to be less significant. Anyway, the point stands: if your answer is useful to people other than OP themselves, feedback will come sooner or later.

Comment: [Even niche can go crazy](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22290599/timeline)

Comment: *the goal of this site is to build a Q/A repository, rather than mimicking a tutor, helpdesk, or interactive tutorial* SO (inc.) have undermined this to the point where I no longer believe that this is true

Comment: I agree with this answer, but feel the need to add that, at this point, the encyclopedia is mostly complete. Localized questions and those about newer, "edge" technologies  are about the only valid ones left. This is both good and bad imo. It is good for the repository, but may prove bad for the rep economy.

Answer (score 32):

I share your frustration.  I try to keep these things in mind:

1. The user may be so inexperienced in the use of the site that s/he can't figure out how to respond to feedback.
2. The user may have forgotten they asked here, or may have lost the link to their question, and are therefore unable to see the requests for feedback (or, it's true, any answers to their question).
3. The user may have figured out their answer (with or without help from SO), and not be coming back any more.

These are all variously frustrating, annoying, or sad, but obviously *there's nothing whatsoever we can do about them*.  SO questioners (like most answerers) are just logins in the ether of the net -- we have no way to reach them other than here, and if that doesn't work, there's no communication at all.

The other thing I try to keep in mind is that helping people here (or trying to help them) is a pretty pure form of altruism.  You may never get any reward for helping someone, you may not even get any feedback that you have helped them at all.  Sometimes, just the thought that you *might* have helped them (or someone else who comes across your answer) has to be enough.

(What's even more frustrating for me than the unresponsive poster is the one who tries to respond, but is having so much trouble with both their problem domain and with SO mechanics that it ends up being impossible for them to provide the information I/we need in order to solve their problem.  But that's a different question.)

Comment: Ad 2. Shouldn’t OP get e-mail notification for feedback by default? Can anyone register without a valid e-mail address? I think a reminder comment should help here, just like for the case 3.

Comment: I believe altruism is really the key here, and trying to learn as much as possible from researching the answer, this way you're effort will always be worth no matter if it will be shown gratitude from OP

Comment: @Melebius I have email feedback turned off, and I don't recall explicitly turning it off.  So unless I'm mis-remembering or the default has changed since I joined, they might not see it unless they remember to check back.

Comment: _"The user may be so inexperienced in the use of the site that s/he can't figure out how to respond to feedback."_ You'd pretty much have to have never used a computer before. This is really not an excuse. #2/#3 are spot on though

Comment: Yes, +1, but I like *upvotes* and *acceptances.* I like to earn rep and, indeed, that is what rep is for, isn't it? It's a reward, and it works, which is apparently why SO has succeeded where countless newsgroups and fora before it had failed. If SO management heeded my advice, they might try to adjust for this.

Answer (score 11):

If the question is good, isn't an obvious duplicate, and you can answer, answer it, you'll get upvotes (even if you don't, at least you've solved an interesting problem/did some research that helped *you*).

*Also don't forget to upvote the question* as it encourages newcomers and makes their question more visible (see my other question about that: [Why don't questions get that much upvote love?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359703/why-dont-questions-get-that-much-upvote-love)).

Now, if the question is bad or unclear, you can just comment to ask for clarification / attempt an answer-in-comments there and let OP respond to the comments:

- If OP doesn't respond, doesn't matter, at least you didn't sweat to post an actual answer, and you already helped, move on.
- If OP responds/edits the post, well, now you can answer, there's a good chance you get at least an acceptance.

That's all there's to it. As your experience on the site grows, you'll be less and less tempted to answer poor questions on-the-spot anyway (well, hopefully)

Comment: +1 about upvoting questions, I think most high rep users here are really tight on question upvotes, sometimes it can be really useful to keep new users engaged and encourage them while my impression is that only perfect wiki-like questions or difficult to solve problems gain upvotes. Also agree about "testing" OP with with some comment before rushing to answer.

Comment: @filippo some high-rep users are tight on upvotes but prolific on answering those to get rep :) Sometimes I just don't upvote an answer because the question doesn't even have the vote of the answerers... see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359703/why-dont-questions-get-that-much-upvote-love

Comment: yeah, my impression exactly, good points on your question there

Comment: "*Also don't forget to upvote the question as it encourages newcomers and makes their question more visible*" You should only upvote the question if it is worthy of being upvoted. Merely being answerable is too low a bar for upvoting. Upvote *good* content, not middling or barely-acceptable content.

Comment: @NicolBolas it's in the context of "If the question is good,", not otherwise.

Comment: @NicolBolas as pointed in the linked question, sometimes the question is apparently worth plenty of answers but it's not good enough to gain even a single upvote... I doubt a single encouragement vote can hurt on a good enough question.

Comment: @filippo: The number of answers a question gets is not based on the question's quality. They get lots of answers based on how visible they are and how easy they are to answer. The easier the question, the more people who can answer it. So simply pointing to a question with fewer upvotes than answers says nothing.

Comment: It's worth noting that [an unresponsive OP can be a valid reason to downvote](http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive), especially if the question was less-than-perfect to begin with and not all of the issues can be fixed via editing.

Comment: @EJoshuaS that unfortunately is out of the way if you already upvoted the question on its own merit and OP turns out to be unresponsive and disappears after your answer. You cannot retract your vote unless OP edits the questions, let alone downvote it.

Comment: @filippo: Or if anyone else edits it.  e.g. tweak the tags or improve the formatting yourself so you can change your vote.

Comment: @PeterCordes cool, sounds a bit like a loop hole, but nice to know nonetheless

Comment: @filippo: yes, don't make a habit of it, unless you can really justify the edit on its own merit.  It's ok in *rare* cases to fix an actual mistake (misclick, or you later realize you misinterpreted a post), but generally don't do it if your original vote was what you intended at the time.

Answer (score 7):

It might help to switch away from thinking that you are answering questions for the OP; you are answering questions to benefit the programming community as a whole.

The OP might not ever respond to your answer but somewhere down the line, someone will search for the same question and find may find your answer useful and give you your late rewards.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the question is otherwise on-topic...

- If the question is not clear, and I may or may not be able to guess what OP wants:

  - I vote / flag to close.
  - I don't answer.
  - I may leave a comment asking for clarification.
  - I trust that, if OP clarifies their post, the community will reopen it.
- If the question is clear and I know the answer (and I want to answer):

  - I answer.
  - I might stick around for a few hours I suppose mostly to remember to check notifications, or maybe it's just a pointless habit, or maybe it's to see whether there's any activity on the question that might affect my answer.
  - I trust that OP will read my answer eventually and find it useful (or has already done so).
- If the question is clear and I have something OP could try which may or may not work (or I can't explain the solution):

  - I generally don't answer.
  - I may leave a comment instead
  - or just let someone else answer.
  - In any case, I trust that it will all work out for OP.

TL;DR: Trust.

Another thing to think about is how important these things really are.

Even if they don't manage to figure it out, it probably won't be the end of the world (and if it would be, the next step for them should be to escalate - add a bounty, pay someone, ask their boss, phone a friend, etc. - still not something you should really concern yourself over).

Also, similar to what the another answer said, you should aim to help more than just the asker, in which case their lack of feedback shouldn't be too important to you.

And if it's about reputation, you should post *enough* good answers so the lack of reputation from one here and there doesn't bother you so much.

Comment: "clear" isn't a sufficient standard for being worth answering.  e.g. a homework assignment question that seems to be just asking for the answer may be clear, but a poor question for SO.  Sometimes I answer or hint in a comment because I already spent the time reading and understanding the question to see what they were asking.  I sometimes don't mind helping that one person if I can quickly type a useful comment, but I may also downvote if there's no future value (i.e. the "not useful" reason).  My thought process is "here's some help, now go away and stop polluting SO".

Comment: @PeterCordes Sure, that's why I said "assuming the question is otherwise on-topic" - I focused on clarity (and guessing) because that seems like the case(s) where one is most likely to want feedback from OP, to find out whether assumption made were correct or whether the solution actually works.

Answer (score 1):

Why does it even matter? Are you here to help people in need of help or just here to get rep points? Personally, if I helped someone with something then my job is done. Any rep points or upvotes are just bonuses. There are worse things to worry about :)

Comment: There are a lot of people who aren't that into the gamification stuff. New users don't even know about it.  This creates a bit of a cultural conflict with the people who love the gamification and creating complex rules around it.

Comment: As I said, quite honestly, I do because it helps to keep me updated, tackle new problems, learn something myself and obviously procrastination. Sometimes though you just do it to help OP with an issue you see an easy solution for and he doesn't, so you tend to wait for some kind of feedback. And I'm not talking about upvotes, these users usually don't understand the rep system yet and they often just say _thanks_ and that's perfectly fine for me. As emerged here those questions are maybe left alone, being an help desk is not the purpose of this community.

Comment: @filippo You have that backwards.  The purpose of the site is to create a useful repository of knowledge to the programming community.  Not to entertain people posting answers by giving them fun problems to solve.  The latter is perfectly fine.  It's not *bad*, but it's not the *purpose* of the site. The *purpose* is to create useful posts that will help other people.  That said, I'm still not seeing how you not getting Imaginary Internet Points for posting your answers prevents you from accomplishing your own goals.

Comment: @Servy uh? the purpose of the site and the motivation anyone who likes to contribute has are two different things, I don't think you or anyone here should have a say about anyone else motivation, what matters is the outcome. About _fake internet points_ did you really read my comment? or my question?

Comment: @filippo *You* are the one who brought up the purpose of the community.  In never said you weren't allowed to have whatever motivations you want to have.  In fact I specifically said that your motivations were fine.  It's okay that your personal motivations are different from the community's purpose (because they don't need to conflict with each other).

Comment: @Servy I might have misinterpreted your comment then. Non-native speaker, sorry. The purpose of the site was brought up in a specific context, referring to _helpdesk_ kind of questions which I sometimes tend to answer and they often have unresponsive OPs. The whole motivation thing instead was indeed to stress this discussion has nothing to do with _Imaginary Internet Points_

Answer (score -3):

My answer comes eight months late but I have something new to add, so here goes.

1. **Rewards.** Reputation (rep) is a reward. By design, earning site privileges is fun. If you are under a certain age, then you might not remember how countlessly many help forums and newsgroups had failed, collapsing in social chaos, before Stack Overflow finally discovered a formula that worked. A large part of what distinguished Stack Overflow's formula from earlier ones was in the way it handles rep.
2. **Senior users.** Admittely, over 25k rep, no more site privileges remain to be earned, and plenty of senior users over 25k continue nonetheless to answer lots of questions just because they like to contribute, but see: these senior users have earned their place in the community. These senior users enjoy the implicit respect of us who remain junior to them. These senior users have earned their stake. The stake itself—more valuable, harder earned than mere rep—has become the reward.
3. **Social status.** Few among the senior users care much about rep, but at their level, *not caring becomes a sign of social status* within the community.
4. **Junior users.** We more junior users are supposed to care about rep. Rep is supposed to motivate us, isn't it? That is what rep is for. Otherwise, there would be little purpose in the awarding and tracking of rep. They do not pay us in cash, after all; they pay us in rep.

Therefore, I would bring the following to the attention of the Stack Overflow team. If they want questions by new users actually answered by users like me (I do not claim that they necessarily do or should want this, but if they do), then they might consider additional measures to boost the likelihood that answers to questions asked by new users be rewarded with rep.

One small suggestion: when the new user types, "Thanks," in comments, then the system might present the new user a banner suggesting that they upvote and accept. This suggestion would probably not alone solve the problem but, combined with other suggestions, it could help.

Further ideas might occur.

**ALTERNATE CONSIDERATIONS AND CONCLUDING REMARKS**

Now, perhaps the issue I raise is judged not to be a problem. Perhaps the view of Stack Overflow's management is that answers to the questions of new users tend to be a waste of time. Perhaps answers to the questions of new users are so seldom of value to future visitors that management would rather that users like me politely ignore most such questions. If so, I could understand this.

However, if the foregoing is not the view of Stack Overflow's management then a substantial adjustment of incentives to answerers would seem to be in order. I for one am gradually growing wary (I did not say, weary) of answering new users' questions. I am gradually adjusting my behavior to the rewards on offer.

If management has indeed been thinking about the problem, if management agrees that it might indeed be a problem, then I should be interested to learn of countermeasures under consideration or in deployment.

Comment: The reward system which "gamifies" the site is only part of the story. The success of Stack Overflow is more appropriately attributed to the curation of its content, on how it is organized and cleaned for future visitors, thus becoming the first hits of programming queries on your favourite search engine. The rep system is just an inventive towards contributing with questions and answers, and a mechanism for granting privileges designed to further fulfill the site's goals.