# Askers who never respond (not new users, not low rep users). Users who remain active, but don't respond

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, answers, new-users

What would be the correct way to deal with askers who never ever respond?

I see that a user (not necessarily a new one) asks a question...and people with huge rep to lowest rep answer it. However, the OP never responds about anything...people put time in his code...suggest a solution, but the OP never says anything.

He/she sees the solutions...comments...but... just, simply chooses not to respond. However, he/she is still here. Should we just ignore it? Delete answer and move on? Or could there be a feature to remind him that he/she has asked a question...there are answers...perhaps they should say something?

Comment: Why should they say something? The post is for everyone, no? Of course it's their original Question, but a post doesn't inherently need the author to be involved unless it needs clarifications that others cannot edit in. Also, they don't need to vote or accept any Answers. That's all voluntary.

Comment: If you think the answer is good, upvote it. If a user repeatedly doesn't respond to answers, by not accepting any, then they will (gradually) lose the interest of some regular users anyway when they see them asking. Though it's never a requirement to respond, or accept a solution on your question, it is seen as a courtesy and some (including myself) won't answer questions from users who repeatedly don't at least offer "thanks" to those they have asked for "free" help from.

Comment: I got accept votes 6 to 8 years after posting an answer. There is no hurry. Our awesomeness will be confirmed, eventually.

Comment: "Delete answer and move on?" - keep in mind that you're not there to help the OP. You're there to answer the question, with the purpose of helping anyone that reads it. Deleting the answer out of spite does more damage than you think.

Comment: I got it from one of the duplicates. ***Ping once the user. If unresponsive, move on and find better questions to answer*** ..Sounds good.

Comment: @Scratte You misunderstand. It's not about accepting or votes. You yourself learn when you answer questions. The feedback helps you correcting errors/oversight in your answer/methodology. That was my point.

Comment: As others have said, I'd just advise to answer when there is benefit to *other* than the asker. If you think you can benefit from answering, then do it. I did that a few times and I really think I was better off from it, even if the only thing I got from the answer was knowledge and experience. If you think you *know* the answer but it might help others, also feel free to post it. You might be surprised that you get few upvotes years later. The goal of an answer is not just the here and now. It remains for *many* future visitors. Even yourself.

Comment: @VLAZ If I post an answer where the question is not an MRE. The OP ghosts. I have no way of knowing weather the answer gives the desired result or not and neither does ANYONE ELSE. See my point? :)

Comment: @AbrarAhmed That is not entirely correct. I will comment if I see an incorrect Answer, even if it is not my Question. I will also get comments on Answers that are from other answerers or "passers by".

Comment: @AbrarAhmed in those cases you *shouldn't* be posting an answer. You should be instead flagging for closure with **needs improvement** -> **A community-specific reason** -> **Needs debugging details**. Alternatively **needs improvement** -> **Needs details or clarity** also works.

Comment: @Scratte If I post an answer where the question is not an MRE. The OP ghosts. I have no way of knowing weather the answer gives the desired result or not and neither does ANYONE ELSE. See my point? Not everyone is worried about upvotes/accepts. I do this as a hobby. I am not even in IT sector.

Comment: @VLAZ I think you didn't understand my comment.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by not MRE. Do you mean a HowTo Quesions that's perfectly answerable, or a debugging Question that is lacking the details that it needs to be answerable? (BTW: There's no point in repeating your own comment with different users. We can all read all the comments.)

Comment: @AbrarAhmed I did. You want to answer a question that *cannot be answered*. If you lack the necessary information upfront, then the question should be put on-hold until this information is provided.

Comment: @Scratte For future viewers. They have to go by the question!. what else do they have. If someone posts 100 line `flask` code and asks how do I refresh my `HTML` ..I tell them to include a `meta refresh` in their HTML. Now they are worried about their `jinja`. So, another viewer won't learn anything unless OP gives a deciding verdict..or at the very least it will be very helpful to a passerby. That is just beyond argument.

Comment: @AbrarAhmed A Question should not have a follow up question.. That's material for another Question in another post.

Comment: @Scratte I don't know what you even mean. Who said anything about a follow up question? It's like..Now, it is says "this error" then you realize "Ah" I missed a space" You correct it. Now, that answer helps everyone. Otherwise the missed space remains there for the benefit of NO ONE.

Comment: Then I do not understand what you mean by "Now they are worried about their `jinja`" Also, anyone can spot a typo.. that's not exclusive to the Question author.

Comment: @Scratte This is getting unproductive. Good day.

Comment: I think I'm getting the picture now. ["It is a good idea to let people know that you are alive and kicking after you have asked a question."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64950901/how-do-i-make-it-such-that-i-can-locate-all-the-insect-names-on-the-website/64951573#comment114866884_64950901) and [this similar one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64949684/beautifulsoup-give-me-list-empty/64950983#comment114870093_64949684) is considered irrelevant to the topic of the Question. If someone flags those as "No Longer Needed" the comments will quickly be removed.

Comment: @Scratte Did you miss this comment of mine? I got it from one of the duplicates. Ping once the user. If unresponsive, move on and find better questions to answer ..Sounds goo

Comment: That applies to unanswerable Questions, no? :) Those that should *not* be answered, because it's unclear what the Question is about. Unless you're just in it for the reputation and want the checkmark, which you can't get unless the asker is around.

Comment: @Scratte I don't think you understand. My question is about OPs who ask a question, you anwser it and THEN they ghost.

Comment: I understand that. There's nothing wrong with it. If we required the asker to stick around, Stack Overflow would be more like a helpdesk, than a collection of all kinds of programming Questions. See [this Answer by Baum mit Augen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369667/12695027)