# Asking a question and then going for vacation

Tags: discussion

I come across this at various times. A user asks a question and then he never replies whether the solution worked for him or he needs more explanation.

What can I do in this case, when you have devoted some good time solving the problem?
The asker is online and still does not reply. Is it some sort of bullying to solution providers?

Comment: There's no need to do anything. If an answer is good it will help other people coming in from Google, which is the main audience in the first place.

Comment: hey! Askers need vacation too... after all the stress of posting ...

Comment: You can't *require* anyone to do anything. If your system *requires* that people do specific things at specific times, you'll fail, because there will always be people that don't do those things or don't do them at the time you want them to.

Comment: Don't worry about it: [Long time until answer accepted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272318/1115360)

Comment: It is kind of fun when every so often, an answer gets accepted months (or even years) after it has been posted.

Answer (score 10):

Good Q&A don't need authors to stay on the site and be useful.

Can you (as a random user) determine by looking at the question and answer(s) if the answer actually answers the question?

If yes - nothing need to be done (maybe upvote one or both depending on quality).

If no - act on that - most likely it means the question is not clear enough which should result in vote to close and possibly downvote. A comment would likely be useless in this case as you expect the author to never show up, but you are free to type one up anyway.

Note that OP may not find any answers useful (or have low reputation) so they can't upvote and possibly there is no answer *most useful for them* to accept - so no particular interaction with the question and answers are needed/possible. Comments like "I found other solution" are not useful, will be flagged as such and should not be provided in a first place leaving Q&A in the state you are asking about.

---

Indeed asking and leaving is *not* what SO ["how to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) recommends, but being present after asking is not a requirement:

> After you post, leave the question open in your browser for a bit, and see if anyone comments. If you missed an obvious piece of information, be ready to respond by editing your question to include it. If someone posts an answer, be ready to try it out and provide feedback!

Comment: "If you missed an obvious piece of information, be ready to respond by editing your question to include it." misses out "*otherwise we may downvote it to oblivion, close it, and then delete it.*"

Answer (score 4):

> What to do in this case, when you have devoted some good time solving the problem. The asker is online and still do not reply, is it some sort of bullying to solution providers??

Unfortunately, you can't do much then. You see, even sending a comment asking for clarification "is the answer is sufficient, of do you need more information?" or something alike can get you flagged and sanctioned when you do it too often.

Thus: when the OP walks away after asking, or never accepts, or comments or whatnot, you can do exactly nothing.

And yes, me personally, I find such behavior deeply annoying. Sure, sometimes people just lost interest, and really walk away. But people who regularly come this network to post content, they should their appreciation according to the rules of this place.

From that point of view, the only thing you can do: remember that username, and avoid answering future questions. And of course, if you notice a low quality post by that user, you can always react in appropriate ways to that.

Comment: *cough* Targeted voting is also something we don't condone… Just vote on the post itself, not on the person please.

Comment: @deceze And I didnt say to do targeted voting.

Comment: You're sort of implying it with your last paragraph, so I just want to caution a bit there…

Comment: The last sentence in particular seems questionable, since you should be doing that with *all* low quality posts. There's no reason to single out ones by that user unless you're deliberately targeting them.